# Why doesn't the distance change?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to create a code that instantly makes my UI appear when close enough to an object that can be interacted with.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class pop_up : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private CanvasGroup myUIGroup;

    public float maxDistance;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject interactible;

    public float distance;

    void update()
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, interactible.transform.position);
        if (distance <= maxDistance)
        {
            ShowUI();
        }
        else
        {
            HideUI();
        }
    }

    public void ShowUI()
    {
        myUIGroup.alpha = 1;
    }

    public void HideUI()
    {
        myUIGroup.alpha = 0;
    }
}
```

I tried to walk close to the object and have the UI appear, but nothing changed and the distance stayed 0.

Comment: Where do you set the initial value for _maxDistance_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is case sensitive, it should be `void Update()` not `void update()`.